# Why in the relativistic quantum mechanics $ \gamma_4$ name is not used instead of $ \gamma_5$?

Tags: special-relativity, notation, dirac-matrices

I have seen in the in the Dirac equation $$\gamma_0,\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3.$$ Then I have seen the definition of a new matrix $$\gamma_5=i\gamma_0\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3.$$ Now my question is why the name of the new matrix has not been given as $$\gamma_4.$$ Is there any historical reason behind this or it is simply taken as $$\gamma_5$$ without any special reason skipping $$\gamma_4~?$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#The_fifth_gamma_matrix.2C_.CE.B35):

> The number 5 is a relic of old notation in which $\gamma^0$ was called "$\gamma^4$".

Comment: Why would anyone in their right mind start their indices at $1$?

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm not sure but it it is not uncommon in general for the notation used in physics and mathematics to change over time.

Comment: @Hunter: Hah, I think JanDvorak was joking...

Comment: It's worth emphasizing that the use of the index 0 for the temporal coordinate is more or less recent. Many texts, some of them not that old, take time, energy, and electrostatic potential to be the 4th (instead of 0th) component of the corresponding four-vectors.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I actually wrote that in the beginning, but I editted because I wasn't sure. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know is there is a historical reason I just assumed that was just no to mistake it with $\gamma^3$ which would be called $\gamma^4$ if your Lorentz indices run from $\mu=1,2,3,4$ instead of the usual $\mu=0,1,2,3$.