# What happened to $\gamma^4$?

Tags: special-relativity, notation, dirac-matrices

Kind of a simple question, but I was looking up some things related to the Dirac equation, and I noticed something about the $\gamma$ matrices. There's $\gamma^0,\,\gamma^1,\,\gamma^2,\,\gamma^3$, which form a "4-vector" of matrices, and then there's $\gamma^5$ which has something to do with chirality. But there's clearly one missing: $\gamma^4$. Why was it skipped? (Was it skipped?)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101612/2451

Comment: Well, that's anticlimactic. I guess this should be marked as a duplicate then.